# Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $f ∈ L(V )$. Show that there is an invertible $g ∈ L(V )$ such that $gfgf = gf$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $F$, and $f \in L(V )$. Show that there is an invertible $g \in L(V )$ such that $gfgf = gf$.

Not sure where to start.. would someone please point me to the significance of invertibility to the result of $gfgf = gf$?

Comment: Well if you didn't assume invertibility then you could take $g = 0$.

Comment: Well, invertability is part of the problem, unfortunately.

Comment: I think @oxeimon gets that; they were just answering your request as to why invertibility might be important.

Comment: More interesting side-question: Why is $V$ required to be finite-dimensional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $v_1, \dots, v_m$ be a basis of the range of $f$. For each $j = 1,\dots, m$, there exists $w_j \in V$ such that
$$
fw_j = v_j.
$$
Because the list $v_1, \dots, v_m$ is linearly independent, the list
$w_1, \dots, w_m$ is also linearly independent.

Let $n = \dim V$. Thus the linearly independent lists $v_1, \dots, v_m$ and $w_1, \dots, w_m$ can each be extended to bases
$$
v_1, \dots, v_m, \dots, v_n \quad \text{ and } \quad w_1, \dots, w_m, \dots, w_n
$$
of $V$. Define $g$ to be the linear map from $V$ to $V$ such that
$$
gv_j = w_j
$$
for $j = 1, \dots, n$. The range of $g$ includes the spanning list $w_1, \dots, w_n$. Hence $g$ is surjective, which implies that $g$ is invertible.

For $j = 1, \dots m$, we have
$$ \tag{1}
(gf)(w_j) = g(fw_j) = gv_j = w_j.
$$
To show that $gfgf = gf$, suppose $w \in V$. Then $fw$ is in the range of $f$, and thus there exist $a_1, \dots, a_m \in F$ such that
$$
fw = a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_m v_m.
$$
Applying $g$ to both sides of the equation above gives
$$(gf)(w) = a_1 w_1 + \dots + a_m w_m.\tag{2}
$$
Applying $gf$ to both sides of the equation above, we have
\begin{align}
(gfgf)(w) &= a_1 (gf)(w_1) + \dots a_m (gf)(w_m)\\
&= a_1 w_1 + \dots + a_m w_m, \tag{3}
\end{align}
where we have used equation (1).

Comparing (2) and (3), we conclude that $gfgf = gf$, as desired.