# For every matrix $A$ there exists a matrix $B$ such that ${(AB)}^{2}=AB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show for every $ n\times n$ matrix $A$ there exists a matrix $B\ne0$ such that ${(AB)}^{2}=AB$.

Comment: For example, $B=0$, the zero matrix?

Comment: If B is non-zero, $B = A^{-1}$

Comment: @ZackNi $A$ may not be invertible

Comment: Solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552483/let-v-be-a-finite-dimensional-vector-space-over-a-field-f-and-f-%e2%88%88-lv) under more restrictive conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you have at least one non-zero choice.

The adjugate matrix of $A$, $M=\mathrm{adj}(A)$, is the transpose of the cofactor matrix of$A$, and satisfies $AM=MA=\det(A)I_n$.

So if $A$ invertible set $B=A^{-1}$ and if $A$ not invertible set $B=\mathrm{adj}(A)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

**EDIT:** This doesn't work if $\operatorname{rank}A<n-1$. So new answer:

If $A$ invertible set $B=A^{-1}$. If not, $A$ will have a right eigenvector $v$ satisfying $Av=0$ (since $A$ must have a zero eigenvalue). Hence set $B=(v, v,...,v)$, i.e. the matrix whose every column is simply $v$. Then $AB=0$.

Comment: I don't see why this works. $(AM)^2 = AM AM = det(A)^2 I \neq AM = det(A) I$ unless $det(A) \in \{0,1\}.$

Comment: We only use $ \textrm{adj}(A) $ if $ A $ is not invertible, in which case $ \det(A) = 0 $.

Comment: Ah, I see, I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1):

If rank of $A$ is 0 there is nothing to prove as B can be chosen to be any matrix such that $AB$ is square, otherwise let $$A = \sum_{i=1}^{r} \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$ ( here $\sigma_1 > \dots \sigma_r > 0$ and $u_i$'s are orthonormal and $v_i$'s are also orthonormal) and we can choose $$B = \sum_{i=1}^r \frac{1}{\sigma_i} v_i u_i^T.$$

$AB = \sum_{i=1}^{r} u_i u_i^T$ is clearly idempotent.

For general fields:
Let $P$ be projection matrix on column space of $A$ along any complement of column space of $A$. Column space of $P$ is same as column space of $A$ so $P = AB$ for some $B$ and $P$ is idempotent.

Comment: Well, maybe the matrices $A$ and $B$ have entries in an *arbitrary* field.

Comment: @user26857 updated answer.